# Embedded filtering in mongodb simple rest api

Tags: mongodb, rest, mongodb-query

The [simple rest api](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/#simple-rest-api) allows queries such as

> http://127.0.0.1:28017/databaseName/collectionName/?filter_a=one

To match

```
{a: "one"}
```

How can one match nested fields such as

```
{a: {b: "one"} }
```

?

Comment: what if you try http://127.0.0.1:28017/databaseName/collectionName/?filter_a.b=one

Comment: Works, thanks! Please make it an answer.

Comment: done that... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like below should work

> http://127.0.0.1:28017/databaseName/collectionName/?filter_a.b=one